# Resizing polymer combo paper-dropdown-menu on dropdown

Tags: javascript, combobox, polymer

I have a combo dropdown in which items are populated dynamically.

Unless I don't set an initial width of the items by assigning some dummy values
like

```
this.processlist = ['aasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf'];
```

with a specific length of text, the combo dropdown doesn't resize automatically for the dynamically generated values.

I read somewhere that we would need to resize the scroller width and height, i tried that but it's not working. Maybe I'm doing it in the wrong place 
https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dropdown/issues/2

I'm new to web development and polymer.

Your help would be appreciated.

Below is the code

```
   <paper-dropdown-menu id="ProcessCombo" label="Process">
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" on-core-overlay-open="{{comboDrop}}">
        <core-menu class="menu">
         <template repeat="{{processlist}}">
              <paper-item>{{}}</paper-item>
            </template>
        </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>

      comboDrop:function(){

         var self = this;

         if (self.focused) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                  self.$.ProcessCombo.dropdown.$.scroller.style.height = ""
                  self.$.ProcessCombo.dropdown.$.scroller.style.width = ""
                  self.$.ProcessCombo.dropdown.open();
               }, redrawFix);
           }

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

this is all the code which I had to put

```
var self = this;
self.$.ProcessCombo.dropdown.$.scroller.style.height = ""
self.$.ProcessCombo.dropdown.$.scroller.style.width = ""
```

in my comboDrop function. And this works even without setting processlist to an initial value.